# Why run cnosdb docker image in MacOS(m2 chip) failed?

Tags: cnosdb

I tried to use cnosdb docker image on MacOS, but it failed to run.
This is my running command:

```
docker run --name cnosdb -p 8902:8902 -d cnosdb/cnosdb:community-latest cnosdb run -M singleton
```

and this is my error message:

```
qemu-x86_64: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?